# In iOS, why does a SceneKit depth of field go faster than a SpriteKit one?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, blur, scenekit

In SpriteKit, you can blur nodes with an `SKEffectNode`, and setting the `CIFilter` to a Gaussian Blur.

In SceneKit, you can make a depth of field blur by changing properties of the scene camera (`focalDistance`, `focalBlur`, and `focalSize`).

Why does SceneKit's blur still give consistent 60 FPS, but SpriteKit's only gives 20 FPS? I'm using an iPhone 6.

Is it because SpriteKit's is on the main thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy!

Gaussian Blur is a very intensive operation. For a 10 radius, it will sample all pixels in a 21x21 square, or 441 samples. For a 1080p HD image, that's almost a billion samples per frame. Obviously there is a lot of optimisations that can be done, but the general idea is this.

2 passes fast blur, which is probably the way Scenekit is doing depth of field, is slightly a cheat: Instead of sampling a square, the shader samples a vertical line (and blurs on only one axis) and blurs it. A second pass samples the blurred image is then blurred on the horizontal axis, making a fairly decent blur that only uses 41 samples per pixel, or 85M samples a frame. 90% less samples!

If you take into account other operations than sampling, you can see why Scenekit is faster.

By the way, using `CIDiskBlur` will give you results more appropriate than Gaussian Blur for DOF. You can also replicate the fast blur in Core Image by stacking two `CIMotionBlur` with 0 and 90 degrees angles.

Comment: Hm. That's not actually true for Gaussian Blur. Gaussian blur [has the 'separable' property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_blur#Implementation) where the X and Y passes can be done separately. But I think you're right in that the Scenekit blur 'cheats' by using an even cheaper algorithm.